# php unlink. returns no error message and doesn't delete my file

Tags: php, file-io

I'm simply trying to delete a file using PHP's unlink. I found an answer on here that told me the best way to do this and I implemented it.  Heres the code I am using.

```
$log_path = realpath($log_file);
if (is_readable($log_path)){
    print file_exists($log_path);
    $deleted = unlink($log_path);
    print "Deleted:".$deleted;
    print "Exists:".file_exists($log_path);
}
```

This just prints `1Deleted:exists:1`. I also tried to add in `print_r(error_get_last());` under the unlink, but this also returned nothing. All files in the directory are `chmod 777 *` and there are no other file handlers open. ....what the heck...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code you used is needlessly cumbersome. A simple call to unlink should do the trick:

```
unlink( $log_file );
```

But let's find out what is going wrong. The file exists, because you enter the loop where the print statements are done. The `unlink` call probably returns false, because the output is "11" and not "111".

So my gut says, it must be a file permissions issue. Are you sure the web user has permission to remove the file? Can you show us the folder permissions, for instance by running `ls -la` on the command line and pasting the output?

Comment: `drwxr-xr-x 15 root  root    4096 Aug 19 14:55 .
drwxr-xr-x 24 root  root    4096 Jul 17 15:28 ..
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root  root  124991 Aug 19 13:53 file_in_question`

Comment: That is the permissions for the file I'm trying to delete.  Do you want the permissions for the php file?

Comment: Nope, that's what I meant.. The file permissions look ok, they can't be causing the problem. What happens if you echo the $log_path from PHP, and try to remove it manually from the command line?

Comment: HEY THANK YOU VERY MUCH YOU PUT ME ON THE RIGHT TRACK.  I did a `chmod 777 .` to the directory of the file I was trying to delete.  Thank you sir.

Answer (score 4):

unlink returns either `true` or `false`. If you try to print `false` (`print $deleted;`), this will print an empty string.

Try this instead:

```
print $deleted ? "The file was deleted" : "The file was not deleted";
```

Comment: wow, that's a great line of code.  It returns `The file was not deleted`

Comment: @Rell3oT $deleted is actually false. But when used in concatenation, it is converted to empty string, not to 0. That's why in your new output there is nothing after Deleted:

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to check if **$log_path** is file. Use:

```
if( is_file( $log_path ) AND is_readable( $log_path ) )
```

Also, add next line to begin of your script to show all errors and warnings:

```
ini_set( 'error_reporting', E_ALL );
```

Answer (score 1):

Its not that your files need to be 0777. It also necessary that your directory can be accessed. What's the mod of your directory?

Next: `print $deleted;` apparently print false, which is shown as nothing. Try this: `echo $deleted ? 1 : 0;`

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know the problem, but you should check, if the file is writable and not if it is readable:

```
<?php
$log_file = "/tmp/test.log";
$log_path = realpath($log_file);
echo "Testing: ". $log_path."\n";
if (is_writable($log_path)) {
    echo "exists?  ";
    echo (file_exists($log_path))?"yes\n":"no\n";
    $deleted = unlink($log_path);
    echo "deleted? ";
    echo ($deleted)?"yes\n":"no\n";
    echo "exists?  ";
    echo (file_exists($log_path))?"yes\n":"no\n";
} else {
    echo "file unwritable\n";
}
```

This code works fine for me (yes, it's also messy ;) ).

Comment: I copy and pasted your code in (except the setting of `$log_file` so from $log_path_down`.  This is my output `/path/to/fileTesting: /path/to/file exists? yes deleted? no exists? yes`

Comment: where does the initial `/path/to/file` before testing come from? Are you on a linux or windows system? what does the output of `var_dump(decoct(fileperms($log_path)));` give you?

Answer (score 0):

`file_exists` caches the result of the operation, you should call [clearstatcache()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php) before the second call

Comment: This made no change.  Good tip though.

Answer (score 0):

for me it was promises issue solve it with

```
  chown    -R www-data:www-data      /var/www/
  chmod    -R g+rwx                  /var/www/
  chmod    -R 0755                  /var/www/
```

make sure that php run under user `www-data`in `www.conf` e.g I'm using PHP 7.2 
`nano /etc/php/7.2/fpm/pool.d/www.conf`
Change these values :-

```
listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data
```

Answer (score 0):

`unlink` function in my case just returned `false` everytime. First, thanks to Viktor for this:

> Also, add next line to begin of your script to show all errors and warnings: `ini_set( 'error_reporting', E_ALL );`

It helped me to see warning:

> unlink(): http does not allow unlinking in PHP.

And i finally found the solution, described here https://a1websitepro.com/warning-unlink-http-not-allow-unlinking-php/.

The case is that I use http path to the file, but `unlink` function requires the absolute path to the file from your server.